# Restoring window from the system tray when allowing only one instance of that program

Tags: c#, winapi

ok, the title is pretty long and should tell the problem i'm facing with.

Here is the code when minimizing to icon tray:

```
void MainFormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            }
        }
```

When the program is already opened and in sys tray, and still someone wants to open another instance of it, then:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                bool createdNew = true;
                using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "IPADcommunicator", out createdNew))
                {
                    if (createdNew)
                    {
                        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                        Application.Run(new MainForm());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
                        {
                            if (process.Id != current.Id)
                            {
                                IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null,"IPADcommunicator");
                                SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                                ShowWindow(handle,5);

                                break;
                            }
                        }
...
```

Howeve, it is not working properly. The mainwindow is not restored.
I've googled a lot and haven't found solutions for that problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling SetForegroundWindow() on an invisible window isn't going to work.  There are many other possible failure mode, FindWindow() is a miserable one when you start passing null.

Don't invent this yourself, .NET already has great built-in support for single instance apps.  You can even get a notification when a 2nd copy starts and pass the command line.  Which is what you want here, simply restore the window instead of hacking the API.  The code you need [is here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

After looking through dozens of solutions including the link from Hans, I do not believe that the accepted answer's link will restore an app from the systray. All it seems to be doing is correctly managing a single instance and passing arguments to the single instance.

A more complete solution which was able to manage single instance, restore a minimised window and restore a systray window can be found on codeplex here.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx

It's also extremely simple to incorporate into your own code.