# How to restore the window allowing single instance of the application in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, restore, single-instance

i implemented allowing to open single instance of the application by using the following thread

[Restoring window from the system tray when allowing only one instance of that program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592852/restoring-window-from-the-system-tray-when-allowing-only-one-instance-of-that-pro)

it is working ,but the currently open window is not restoring.I haven't used the MDI Parent concept.To navigate the form just i used the hide() and show(). 
I tried the [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SingleInstanceAppMutex.aspx) link from the above thread.I created first instance and i am in mainform.now i tried to open the second instance of the application, it is restoring the same window.
After navigating to any of the window in the application.if i do the same,now it is opening the mainform in new window along with existing window.If i closed any one, both are closing.

How to modify the code to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt take alook at the link in your post. But i am assuming your using Mutex to launch only 1 instance of the application to load no matter how many times you try to launch it.

If its an child app, then you can have a static object of that child and keep launching the same object with ShowDialog call (Winform).

Comment: No.There is no child apps,it is happening with in the same app

Comment: Then please use Mutex. Hope this helps http://iridescence.no/post/CreatingaSingleInstanceApplicationinC.aspx