# Restore program from system tray clicking shortcuts in desktop in c#

Tags: c#, system-tray

Im using Visual studio 2012, windows form. I need restore application from system tray when I click shortcut on desktop.

Im using this code that prevent double istance of same application, but not open application from system tray.

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string mutex_id = "my application";
        using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, mutex_id))
        {
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
            {
                Form1 fForm;
                fForm = new Form1();
                fForm.Show();
                fForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                fForm.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                // MessageBox.Show("Instance Already Running!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                return;
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

I readed some questions here in stackoverflow, without luck. What I need modify in this code? thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592852/restoring-window-from-the-system-tray-when-allowing-only-one-instance-of-that-pr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14326291/17034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Mutex to accomplish this. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/C-Single-Instance-App-With-the-Ability-To-Restore) is a bolt-on solution from CodePlex, that is very easy to incorporated into your program. The solution does provides the following features:

- If the First Instance is Minimized to the System Tray (aka
  "Notification Area"), Restore It
- Activating the First Instance
- Prevent a Second Instance from Opening

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697058/single-instance-windows-forms-application-and-how-to-get-reference-on-it) and answers with different ideas on getting instance of app that is already running. And check this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163741.aspx (look fo mutex).